# add last column to the file from another file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to add column 2 of FileB in the last column of FileA if the first column of both files matches.

FileA

```
12345,4567,12345,4567
56789,1234,56789,1234
65789,1234,23244,2324
```

FileB

```
12345,MMS
12345,INTERNET
12345,SSS
56789,MS
56789,INTERNET
```

Output

```
12345,4567,12345,4567,MMS,INTERNET,SSS
56789,1234,56789,1234,MS,INTERNET
65789,1234,23244,2324
```

So far, I have this awk

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {$5=a[$1]}1' OFS=, FileB FileA | tr -d '  '
```

which results to

```
 12345,4567,12345,4567,SSS
 56789,1234,56789,1234,INTERNET
```

Comment: what-have-you-tried.awk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=a[$1](a[$1]?",":"")$2;next} a[$1]{$5=a[$1]}1' OFS=, FileB FileA
12345,4567,12345,4567,MMS,INTERNET,SSS
56789,1234,56789,1234,MS,INTERNET
65789,1234,23244,2324
```

This approach guarantees that the order of lines in the output is the same as the order of lines in `FileA`.

#### How it works

- `NR==FNR{a[$1]=a[$1](a[$1]?",":"")$2;next}`

  When reading the first file, `FileB` in this case, we append `$2` to the value of `a[$1]`.  If `a[$1]` already has a value, we add a comma before `$2`.

  The choice to add a comma or not is made with a ternary statement: `(a[$1]?",":"")`.  If `a[$1]` is true (non-empty), then this statement returns `","`.  If not, it returns the empty string, `""`.
- `a[$1]{$5=a[$1]}`

  If `a[$1]` is not blank, make it `$5`.
- `1`

  Print the line

Comment: Since my actual data is too big, I got this error **Internal software error in the symbol table**

Comment: Hmm. We may need a different approach.  In your example, the files are in order according to column 1.  Is that true of the real files?  Also, roughly how big are the real files?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}a[$1]{a[$1]=a[$1]","$2}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' filea fileb
```